# Proof of rate of return on a portfolio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm going crazy here. The question is about indirect calculation on:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return_on_a_portfolio

Let's say our portfolio consist of $n$ different types of assets, each having a weight of $w_i$, $i=1,...,n$, $\sum_{i=1}^nw_i=1$ and a value at time $t$ of $V_{i,t}$. The return of asset $i$ at time $t$ is defined by $r_{i,t}=\frac{V_{i,t}-V_{i,t-1}}{V_{i,t-1}}$.

On Wikipedia it is stated that the return of the whole portfolio at time $t$ is:

$r_t=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_ir_{i,t}$

but I'm not seeing how these things could be equal. All I'm getting, when trying to define $r_t$, is (by definition of return):

$r_t=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_iV_{i,t}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_iV_{i,t-1}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_iV_{i,t-1}}\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\frac{V_{i,t}-V_{i,t-1}}{V_{i,t-1}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_ir_{i,t}$

I'm guessing this shouldn't be a hard proof, but I just can't see it and it's driving me nuts. Could someone help me out here?

Comment: What do you mean by a weight?  I expect your reference has weight as a percent of invested capital, so the weight already incorporates information about the price.  If, instead, you define weight out of some abstract quality (like number of shares) then the formula changes.  Write out a simple portflio.  Say you have one share of $A$ at $100$ and two shares of $B$ at $200$ (both prices are per share).  Now write everything out.

Comment: Yes, the weights are percents, I edited to add that their sum is 1.  A proof by example is not what I'm looking for, I need the mathematical solution that the equation holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the weightings are defined as the proportion that each asset's value represents of the value of the whole portfolio (this is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return_on_a_portfolio#Indirect_calculation) on the linked Wikipedia page), that is:
$$w_i=\frac{V_{i,t-1}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}V_{j,t-1}}$$
$r_t$ is the sum of all the changes in value, divided by the starting value of the whole portfolio:
$$r_t = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(V_{i,t}-V_{i,t-1})}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}V_{j,t-1}} \\ $$
and we can rearrange as follows:

\begin{align}
  r_t & = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{V_{i,t}-V_{i,t-1}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}V_{j,t-1}}\right) \\
  & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{V_{i,t-1}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}V_{j,t-1}}\cdot\frac{V_{i,t}-V_{i,t-1}}{V_{i,t-1}}\right) \\
  & = \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_ir_{i,t}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the equation for $w_i$-s.